# Flex using XML dot notation string

Tags: xml, apache-flex, notation

In the following example the first trace gives me the xml data at the node, but the second trace does not. This is AS3. How would I use a variable to do the same as inline dot notation?

```
var x:String = "animXML.home.version";
trace(animXML.home.version);  // this works
trace([x]);                   // this does not
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi Eduardo, eval is not supported in AS3 Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: As you defined it, x is the string *"animXML.home.version"*. Also, what do you mean by *"How would I use a variable to do the same as inline dot notation"*?

Comment: Hi, In the first trace I would get the actual xml data which in this case would be "Version 1" outputted to the console. In the second trace I see the string "animXML.home.version" outputted to the console.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve but this will output same thing:

```
var x:String = animXML.home.version as String;
trace(animXML.home.version);  // this works
trace(x);                     // this works
```

update (full script):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <fx:Model id="animXML">
            <root>
                <home>
                    <version>Version 1</version>
                </home>
            </root>
        </fx:Model>    
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            protected function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var x:String = animXML.home.version as String;
                trace(animXML.home.version);  // this works
                trace(x);                     // this works
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Button label="test" click="clickHandler(event)" />

</s:Application>
```

Click on "test" button gives the following output:

```
Version 1
Version 1
```

Comment: Hi actually that does not work since the string is a XML dot notation to a node, so the first trace actually goes to the XML and outputs the node data, the second trace above would just output the x string.

Comment: I updated the answer with full code so you can see it works, if this is not what you wanted, please explain. Hope that helps.

Comment: Nice work, but my case is different sorry. The second trace works above since the xml is there in the mxml. In my case the XML is being read in from a external xml file and there is a Bindable variable it is assigned to. When I created my question I tried to make my issue as simple as possible but I did not think of someone doing what you did to solve it, again nice job, but I still have to figure out a way to have the variable with the dot notation be evaluated at run time and not compile time. Thanks.

Comment: When you click on the button it is evaluating the XML at runtime. There is no difference: XML is XML, it is not different from one that you get from a web service. If you think you can better describe your current problem, open another question with details and I'll try to help you. Cheers.